# Opening another windows from mainly window multiple times

Tags: c#

I'm working on project with two windows, main and second which opens when you click button on main window. But when I close second window and then click again on button that open this second window nothing happens. 
I used this to open second window:

```
private void podsumujBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        summary.Show();                    
    }
```

summary is the name of second window's class.
What am I missing?

Comment: Do you get any exception ?

Answer (score 0):

When you close a window it's gone, and it's not coming back.  All of it's resources get cleaned up.

What you want to do is `Hide` the window instead of closing it, assuming it's important to bring it back at some later point in time.  If the window is just hidden then showing it again will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you close window, you need create new window if you want to see it. Do you close Second window or hide?

Comment: I'm closing it by clicking exit on the top bar of the window. So how to hide it ?